# sql update error afer registration

Tags: php, mysql, registration

After creating a form for user registration, I want to add groups.
Now I first tried editing the prepared statement but that did not work, so I tried this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include('connect.php');
// If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $epassword = hash("sha512", $password);
           $group = 'user';

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE email='$email'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($count == 1){
$msg1 = "Dit E-mailadres is al in gebruik voor een andere gebruiker.";

}else{

$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($count == 1){
$msg2 = "Deze gebruikersnaam is al in gebruik.";

}else{

$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (username,password,email) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $epassword, $email);
$stmt->execute();
    $msg = "De gebruiker is aangemaakt.";

$sql2 = "UPDATE user
    SET group = $group
    WHERE username = $username" ;

$retval = mysqli_query( $connection, $sql2);
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}
    }
  }
}
?>
```

and now it is creating the user (with no group) after showing the following error:

```
Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group = user WHERE username = test' at line 1
```

could you help me with this?

thanks to juergen d this is the working code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    include('connect.php');
    // If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
   if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $epassword = hash("sha512", $password);
           $modus = "user";

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE email='$email'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($count == 1){
$msg1 = "Dit E-mailadres is al in gebruik voor een andere gebruiker.";

}else{

$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' ";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($count == 1){
$msg2 = "Deze gebruikersnaam is al in gebruik.";

}else{

$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (username,password,email) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $epassword, $email);
$stmt->execute();
$msg = "De gebruiker is aangemaakt.";

$sql2 = "UPDATE `user`
SET `modus` = '$modus'
WHERE username = '$username'";

$retval = mysqli_query( $connection, $sql2);
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: you should get an PHP error first. Because a if statement can have multiple elseif statement and only one else statement. Here you used two else statement. Are you sure this is the code you are working with?

Comment: this is the code i was working with copy'd directly from te page (there is  a form after this if you need it)

Comment: In that case it should give the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped with backticks.

```
UPDATE user
SET `group` = '$group'
WHERE username = '$username'"
```

And as others already mentioned - put your strings in quotes or better look into *Prepared Statements*.

Comment: now i get:  Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''group' = user WHERE username = 'test1234'' at line 1

Comment: Not quotes - backticks. Have a close look at the symbol before and after `group`.

Comment: @juergend dont u think it should be something like "UPDATE user
SET group = '$group'
WHERE username = '$username'". Thnx

Comment: still not working, changed the group name to "modus" for ease but now i get: Could not update data: Unknown column 'user' in 'field list'.

Comment: wait it works i added single quotes to '$username' will post a edit with the working code above with your name in it

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 user is also the data that needs to be inserted in the group collum

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap strings in apostrophes, just like you did in one of your previous queries; example:

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE `user` SET `group` = $group WHERE username = '$username'";
```

Also, as per [juergen d's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26944691/2788872), you need to enclose the group column in backticks, as it is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE `user`
SET `group` = '$group'
WHERE `username` = '$username'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether mysql allow you to use "group" as column name, but the most obvious error is you need wrap the group value with double quotes: set group="$group"